# Does Spark streaming support to Kafka 1.1.0 now?

Tags: apache-spark

Now the spark version is 2.3.
I have seen the maven central repository: https://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.apache.spark%22

the shown jar is `spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.11`

so the kafka1.1.0 isn't supported now?

i still should install `kafka 0.10.x`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [the following link](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/streaming-kafka-integration.html):
you should use `spark-streaming-kafka-0-10` for kafka 0.10.0 or *higher*.

Answer (score 0):

I have been test `spark2.3` with `kafka1.1.0` using jars

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
     <artifactId>spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.11</artifactId>
     <version>${spark.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

that runs well.

example code:

```
    SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("stream test").setMaster("local[*]");
    JavaStreamingContext streamingContext = new JavaStreamingContext(conf, Durations.seconds(2));

    Map<String, Object> kafkaParams = new HashMap<>();
    kafkaParams.put("bootstrap.servers", "master:9092");
    kafkaParams.put("key.deserializer", StringDeserializer.class);
    kafkaParams.put("value.deserializer", StringDeserializer.class);
    kafkaParams.put("group.id", "use_a_separate_group_id_for_each_stream");
    kafkaParams.put("enable.auto.commit", false);

    List<String> topics = Arrays.asList("A29");

    JavaInputDStream<ConsumerRecord<String, String>> stream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(
            streamingContext,
            LocationStrategies.PreferConsistent(),
            ConsumerStrategies.<String, String>Subscribe(topics, kafkaParams)
    );

    JavaDStream<String> lines = stream.map(ConsumerRecord::value);

    lines.print(30);

    streamingContext.start();
    streamingContext.awaitTermination();
```